# WordPress: How to get plugin options from other plugin page

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress plugin which has a widget, and that widget displays a link on the page like e.g.:

```
<a href="<?php echo plugins_url('/ext_page.php', __FILE__); ?>">Link</a>
```

Now in the /ext_page.php page, I need to get options from the plugin itself like e.g.:

```
$options = get_option('my_plugin_options');
```

But the function get_option seems not working in that page, is there any other way to get the options?

Please kindly advise,
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) will always work on WordPress. Make sure you've written the option name well.

You can use a default value(empty array in this case) in case the option is not found:

```
$options = get_option('my_plugin_options', array() );
```

Go to your `wp_options` table and check if the value for `my_plugin_options` exists or is set.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but maybe I didn't describe my problem clearly. I mean if a file **ext_page.php** was put in plugin directory, e.g.**~/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/ext_page.php**, and I use a browser to access it like **http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/ext_page.php** then **get_option()** is not working.

Comment: you should include the file `wp-blog-header.php` in any external file to be able to use Wordpress functions. That file is in your wordpress root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration, maybe the option is serialized in the `wp_options` database table? In that case, you can retrieve the value as follows:

```
$options = get_option('my_option', 'default text');
$option = $options['field_one'];
```

Option data appears in the `option_value` field. If it's serialized, it will look something like this:

```
a:1:{s:11:"field_one";s:7:"foobar";}
```

For reference: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-a-serialized-option